# Cypress intercept does not match route with status 204

Tags: cypress, e2e, cypress-intercept

I am implementing cypress tests in our Angular application and have a problem waiting for a request to finish. I am guessing it has to do with the status of the Request being 204 instead of 200.

This is the function/command I am calling in my test:

```
export function logout() {
    cy.intercept('/api/security/logout').as('logoutRequest');
    cy.getCookie('SESSION').then((cookie) => {
        if (cookie != null) {
            cy.request(
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/api/security/logout',
                }
            );
        }
    });
    cy.wait('@logoutRequest');
}
```

My problem is, that the route `/api/security/logout` is not recognized as alias `@logoutRequest` and therefore the wait always timeouts. Even though there is a vaild request. As you can see here in the test protocol:
[image: Test Failing]
[image: No matches of route]

I have tried modifing the route with * or ** but without success. I would be very glad if you could help me out.

Comment: Hi. I'm a bit concerned about the structure and suspect that the `.wait('@logoutRequest')` is called before your callback is done. Can you try to chain it in another callback, so you will be sure they are called consecutively. Also, I suggest you to define the method explicitly inside the intercept command ;).

Comment: I get your point, but that differs a bit from what the problem is: The route /api/security/logout is not recognised as the alias @logoutRequest.

Comment: ok, I see it is not either registered or is registered too late. Could you overwrite your intercept with a `cy.log` and check the time it gets called/registered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `cy.intercept()` to catch `cy.request()`.

[cy.intercept(), cy.server(), and cy.route()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#cy-intercept-cy-server-and-cy-route)

> cy.request() sends requests to actual endpoints, bypassing those defined using cy.route() or cy.intercept()

Just chain `.then()` off the request to handle the reply

```js
cy.request({method: 'POST', url: '/api/security/logout', failOnStatusCode: false})
  .then(response => {
    expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
  })
```